# Non-http Protocol Support in windows xp or Windows Server 2003? (net.tcp)

Tags: wcf, iis-7, binding, iis-6, net.tcp

Will it be possible for windows xp or windows server 2003 to support net.tcp for WCF,  well it works in windows server 2008 as IIS 7.0 supports net.tcp,but is there anyway for IIS 5.1 or IIS 6.0 to support net.tcp,is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will have to host it yourself (windows service for example) to use net.tcp.  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx) for a list of hosting options and what transports they can host.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can host non-HTTP bindings in IIS 6.0.  In IIS 7.0 you can use WAS (Windows Activation Services) to host non-HTTP, but I don't think this works in 6.0.

The best alternative for XP or 2003 is to host your non-HTTP endpoints with a ServiceHost in a Windows Service.