# The formatter threw an exception ....The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, app-config

Whenever I try to save the xmlString as a text file through server using wcf Service, I keep getting the following error:

> *The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'saveAnnotations'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has
>   been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by
>   changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.
>   Line 1, position 21897.*

I get this exception whenever I try to save the xmlstring by calling the wcf service.

> *Below are my WebConfig (Client Configuration settings) and AppConfig (Server Configuration settings):*

**Webconfig Settings**

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IConversion"  closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
           maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>    
    <client>      
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8092/ServiceModelSamples/service"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IConversion"
        contract="ConversionEngineService.IConversion" name="WSHttpBinding_IConversion">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/PrasenjitDas-PC" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**AppConfig Settings:**

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="ConversionEngineService.Conversion"
               behaviorConfiguration="ConversionServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8099/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service  -->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8092/ServiceModelSamples/service"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="ConversionEngineService.IConversion"  />
        <!--bindingConfiguration="SecureHttpBinding" name="SecureHttp"-->
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8099/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex/ -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"  />

      </service>

    </services>
      <bindings >
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding"
            messageEncoding="Mtom" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"/>

          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

      <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ConversionServiceBehavior">

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
           <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500"
                   maxConcurrentInstances ="100" 
                  maxConcurrentSessions ="200"/>
          <!--added by hr on 31.10.2013-->
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"  ignoreExtensionDataObject="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Can you show the code...

Comment: possible duplicate of [The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600057/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192-has-been-exceeded-while-reading-x)